# android Asynctask fingerprint error

Tags: android

```
10-22 09:36:23.598 14313-14512/com.exampple.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 14512 (AsyncTask #5)
10-22 09:36:23.703 541-541/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***    *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-22 09:36:23.703 541-541/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/hydrogen/hydrogen:6.0.1/MMB29M/V7.5.4.1.MBCMIDE:user/release-keys'
10-22 09:36:23.704 541-541/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
10-22 09:36:23.704 541-541/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
10-22 09:36:23.704 541-541/? A/DEBUG: pid: 14313, tid: 14512, name: AsyncTask #5  >>> com.exampple.app <<<
10-22 09:36:23.705 541-541/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
10-22 09:36:23.730 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   00000055831f5730  x3   000000558322c1e0
10-22 09:36:23.730 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
10-22 09:36:23.730 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000403  x9   0000007fae1bda70  x10  0000000000000003  x11  0000000000000010
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007fae1bdaf8  x13  00000055830a1c70  x14  00000055829dd000  x15  00000000ebad607f
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fae1b6a58  x17  0000000000000000  x18  00000055831f5730  x19  00000055831f57c8
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x20  00000055831f5730  x21  0000007faae40000  x22  000000006ffaa648  x23  0000007f8b397208
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f8b3972b8  x25  0000007f8b3972d8  x26  0000000070403aaf  x27  000000006ffaa648
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000558325b330  x29  0000007f8b397180  x30  0000007faa941248
10-22 09:36:23.731 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f8b397180  pc   0000007faac62b30  pstate 0000000020000000
10-22 09:36:23.734 541-541/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
10-22 09:36:23.734 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000044fb30  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread28PopDeoptimizationReturnValueEv+24)
10-22 09:36:23.734 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000012e244  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+536)
10-22 09:36:23.734 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000042b2a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+460)
10-22 09:36:23.734 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000459954  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+744)
10-22 09:36:23.735 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000067754  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
10-22 09:36:23.735 541-541/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000001c644  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
10-22 09:36:23.921 541-541/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
10-22 09:36:23.921 541-541/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
10-22 09:36:23.924 1245-15797/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
10-22 09:36:23.931 4751-6427/? E/octvm_klo: read: Unexpected EOF!
10-22 09:36:24.062 1245-1287/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 60)
10-22 09:36:24.087 1245-3077/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b057529 com.exampple.app/com.exampple.app.fragmentbase.Activity_Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-22 09:36:24.095 4859-4863/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
10-22 09:36:24.096 4859-4863/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
10-22 09:36:27.078 4859-4863/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
10-22 09:36:27.084 4859-4863/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
10-22 09:36:27.088 4859-4863/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
```

I dont know where i am facing the error. My Android Phone is Redmi MI Max, Android version,6.0.1. it is i made the API call and success the json data and saving the data using Asynctask background thread,thread saved success fully by on Postexecute not working..here i am not using any fingerprint access. but it is showing fingerprint error.

```
   public void userLogin(String schoolCode, String userName, String password, String deviceId) {
    try {
        boolean isDataSet = false;
        String url = Constants.MAIN_SERVER_URL;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(Params.SCHOOLCODE, schoolCode);
        jsonObject.put(Params.USERNAME, userName);
        jsonObject.put(Params.PASSWORD, password);
        jsonObject.put(Params.DEVICE_ID, deviceId);

        api.call(url, jsonObject, new Api.CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void done(String url, JSONObject jsonObject, AjaxStatus status) {
                boolean isDataSet = false;
                try {
                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        int statusCode = jsonObject.getInt(Params.STATUS);
                        if (statusCode == StatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                            isDataSet = true;
                            JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(Params.DATA);
                            new UserLogInInfoSaving(dataObject).execute();
                        } else {
                            String message = Utils.getValidStringFromJSON(jsonObject, Params.MESSAGE);
                            JSONObject jsonErrorObj = new JSONObject();
                            jsonErrorObj.put(Params.MESSAGE, message);
                            Log.e("ERRROR", " IN DASHBOARD INFORMATION ".concat(status.getMessage()));
                            if (dataCompletedAction != null) {
                                dataCompletedAction.onRecordsCompleted(jsonErrorObj);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, status.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (!isDataSet) {
                        Log.e("ERRROR", " IN DASHBOARD INFORMATION ".concat(status.getMessage()));
                        if (dataCompletedAction != null) {
                            dataCompletedAction.onRecordsCompleted(null);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Check the user log in and i am saving the record into the Database

```
 private class UserLogInInfoSaving extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonObject;


    UserLogInInfoSaving(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DBSchools dbSchools = null;
        try {
   //                Saving school information
            Constants.ACTIVE_USER_ID =    Utils.getValidStringFromJSON(jsonObject, Params.USER_ID);
                if (jsonObject.has(Params.SCHOOL_INFO)) {
                JSONObject jsonSchoolInfoObj =   jsonObject.getJSONObject(Params.SCHOOL_INFO);
                 String newSchoolCode = Utils.getValidStringFromJSON(jsonSchoolInfoObj, Params.SCHOOLCODE);
                if(newSchoolCode!=null && !newSchoolCode.equals("NA")) {
                    dbSchools=DBSchools.set(newSchoolCode, isFirstSchool(), jsonSchoolInfoObj);
                    if(dbSchools!=null) {
                        Constants.CURRENT_SCHOOL_CODE = dbSchools.getSchoolCode();
                        Constants.SERVER_URL = dbSchools.getSchoolUrl();
                        DBParent.set(Constants.CURRENT_SCHOOL_CODE, Constants.SERVER_URL, Constants.ACTIVE_USER_ID, jsonObject);                         
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
         try {
                JSONObject jsonSchoolInfoObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject(Params.SCHOOL_INFO);
                String newSchoolCode = Utils.getValidStringFromJSON(jsonSchoolInfoObj, Params.SCHOOLCODE);
                String parentId = Utils.getValidStringFromJSON(jsonObject, Params.USER_ID);
                JSONArray jsonArray = Utils.getValidJSONArrayFromJSON(jsonObject, Params.STUDENT_INFO);
                                    new StudentInfoSaving(jsonArray, Constants.SERVER_URL, newSchoolCode, parentId).execute();
         }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

When i removed the code from post execute and do it on doInBackgroud method in UserLogInInfoSaving class with the help of runOnUiMethod(), it is working fine. but when its go to postExecute() method of the same class rises the error.

Has anybody seen this kind of error?Help me. I am still stuck with this problem. Helps will be appreciated

Comment: Put your some code snippet.

Comment: Added the core code

Comment: Code look so messy .I would suggest you first try single Asyntask get their  result and make sure not make any UI operation at doInBackground.

Comment: I know . we cannot do any UI update from background thread, i have been mentioned that, I have been used with the help of runOnUiThread() method. why i need to use single Asynctask? is there any restriction on that? i used it for code resuablity.

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging mode, it is caused due to the use of jsonobject in the post execute method since your Params.SCHOOL_INFO is passing a null value to jsonobject